# "Split" returns redundant characters

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a **simple** way of implementing split function. Here is what I have:

```
import Data.List
groupBy (\x y -> y /= ',') "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd"

=> ["aaa",", bbb",", ccc",", ddd"]
```

It's almost what I want except the fact that a delimiter "," and even an extra whitespace are in the result set. I'd like it to be  [`"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]`

So what is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about: *what is your group separator?*

In your case, looks you want to avoid comma and whitespaces, why not?

```
split :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
split separators seq = ...
```

You can group then writing

```
groupBy ((==) `on` (flip elem sep)) seq
```

taking

```
[ "aaa"
, ", "
, "bbb"
, ", "
, "ccc"
, ", "
, "ddd"
]
```

and filter final valid groups

```
filter (not.flip elem sep.head) $ groupBy ((==) `on` (flip elem sep)) seq
```

returning

```
["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]
```

of course, if you want a implemented function, then [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html) is great!

*Explanation*

This `split` function works for any `a` type whenever instance `Eq` class (i.e. you can compare equality given two `a`). Not just `Char`.

A (list-based) string in Haskell is written as `[Char]`, **but** a list of chars (not a **string**) is also written as `[Char]`.

In our `split` function, the first element list is the valid separators (e.g. for `[Char]` may be `", "`), the second element list is the source list to split (e.g. for `[Char]` may be `"aaa, bbb"`). A better signature could be:

```
type Separators a = [a]

split :: Eq a => Separators a -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

or `data`/`newtype` variations but this is another story.

Then, our first argument has the same type as second one - but they are not the same thing.

The resultant type is a *list of strings*. As a string is `[Char]` then the resultant type is `[[Char]]`. If we'd prefer a general type (not just `Char`) then it becomes `[[a]]`.

A example of splitting with numbers might be:

```
Prelude> split [5,10,15] [1..20]
[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9],[11,12,13,14],[16,17,18,19,20]]
```

`[5,10,15]` is the separator list, `[1..20]` the input list to split.

(Thank you very much Nick B!)

Comment: I actually don't understand why "split" gets [a] and [a] instead of [a] and a. And returns [[a]] instead of just [a]. Could you me an example of how you use it?

Comment: Alexander Supertramp: Imagine you wanted to split the string "one::two::three::four" on "::". The delimiter is then of type `[Char]`, not of type `Char`.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the `splitOn` function from the [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html) package:

```
splitOn ", " "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd" -- returns ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]
```

It splits a given list on every occurrence of the complete substring. Alternatively you can also use `splitOneOf`:

```
splitOneOf ", " "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd" -- returns ["aaa","","bbb","","ccc","","ddd"]
```

Although it returns some empty strings it has the advantage of splitting at one of the characters. The empty strings can be removed by a simple `filter`.